# React Select Options not showing

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I need to modified some of react-select components ( NoOptionsMessage, Option).

```
function NoOptionsMessage(props) {
  if (props.options.length) return null;
  return (
    <Typography
      className={props.selectProps.classes.noOptionsMessage}
      {...props.innerProps}
    >
      No Result found
    </Typography>
  );
}

function Option(props) {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      buttonRef={props.innerRef}
      selected={props.isFocused}
      component="div"
      style={{
        fontWeight: props.isSelected ? 500 : 400
      }}
      {...props.innerProps}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
```

what i can see, api call properly responsing data and NoOptionsMessage every time called after that. But strangely Option component is not called in some cases.

Here is my render function where i used react-select

```
render() {
    const { classes, options, searchable } = this.props;
    const components = {
      Option,
      NoOptionsMessage
    };
    console.log('result', options); // evertime prints result
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Select
          classes={classes}
          options={options}
          isSearchable={searchable}
          components={components}
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of your code ? Like the `Typography` and `MenuItem` component are missing right now ? Thank you

Comment: Typography and MenuItem both are required from material-ui-core. I actually tried to make a common independent selector component which will be used for other part of my project. [here](https://ideone.com/hcDnoS) is the full code for my selector component.

Comment: Is [this reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/vj985lwjmy) of your code correct ?

Comment: I am really sorry to comment you so late, actually i solved my problem with AsyncSelect